Is there a way to use a subtype definition to constrain an array element?
Say I have the following type definitions:
type my_type is record
   a : std_logic_vector;
end record;

type my_type_a is array (integer range <>) of my_type;

subtype my_subtype is my_type(a(7 downto 0));

I want to create a subtype of my_type_a with the elements contrained by my_subtype. I know I can use a signal of type my_subtype to contrain the elements:
signal sig : my_subtype;
subtype my_subtype_a is my_type_a(open)(a(sig.a'range));

But is there a way to define a subtype of my_type_a with the elements constrained by the my_subtype definition (so I can put it in a package)?  Something like:
subtype my_subtype_a is my_type_a(open)(my_subtype);  -- this doesn't work

I know I can declare a signal in the package and use that but that seems a bit messy and I'm wondering if there's a proper way.

Did you try encapsulating it in a package? I assume you know the package concept in VHDL.

@NaveedAhmed That will not help in this case. You cannot currently constrain a record subtype from another record subtype as part of an unconstrained array definition. See the issue linked in my answer.

Unfortunately, you currently need an object to do this as you have found.
There is an issue raised against the LRM for your exact problem:
https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues/83
The current work around would be to create another array of the subtype, and use the fact the two types are similar and cast between the two.
type my_type_b is array(integer range <>) of my_subtype;


...

signal a : my_type_a(7 downto 0);
signal b : my_type_b(7 downto 0);


b <= my_type_b(a);

